# Maven 3: Is it possible to build a JDBC-3 driver with Java 6?

Tags: java, jdbc, maven-3

I'm writing a simple JDBC driver that should be compliant to JDBC-3 (so it can be used with Java 5 and 6). My build environment is Java 6 and I use Maven 3. I do have Java 5 installed, so I could access Java 5's `rt.jar`.

Is there a save way to compile Java code with Java 6's `javac` against Java 5's `rt.jar`?

Yes, I'm looking for a hack here.

Comment: You mean JDBC spec v3.0, I assume, not a type-3 JDBC driver

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a spec v3.0, type 4 driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to configure the `maven-compiler-plugin`, and especially the `<bootclasspath>` attribute, as shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html)?